# Sending state to parent components with React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a React.js app that is constructed like the following:

```
// App component - represents the whole app
App = React.createClass({
    render() {
      return (

          <div>
            <Landing />
            <Description />
            <Skills/>
          </div>

      );
    }
});
```

where "Landing", "Description" and "Skills" are all children components of the App component.

In Landing, I have a child component called Social Menu, that gets called using:

```
<SocialMenu items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us']} />
```

It looks like this:

```
SocialMenu = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { focused: 0 };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        MichaelReactStore.addChangeListener(this.state.focused);
    },

    clicked: function(index){

        // The click handler will update the state with
        // the index of the focused menu entry

        this.setState({focused: index});
    },

    render: function() {

        // Here we will read the items property, which was passed
        // as an attribute when the component was created

        var self = this;

        // The map method will loop over the array of menu entries,
        // and will return a new array with <li> elements.

        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="testblocks">{ this.props.items.map(function(m, index){

                    var style = '';

                    if(self.state.focused == index){
                        style = 'focused';
                    }

                    // Notice the use of the bind() method. It makes the
                    // index available to the clicked function:

                    return <li key={index} className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;

                }) }

                </ul>



                <p>Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]}</p> 

                <ItemDetails item={ this.props.items[this.state.focused] } />

            </div>
        );

    }
});

ItemDetails = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>{this.props.item}</div>
        );
    }

});
```

What I would like to do is "send the state up" to the App component from the social menu.  Then I would like to send that data down as a prop to the Skills component, where it will show some dynamic data depending on that state.

How would I do this?  Thank you!

(I know this isn't sustainable for a larger app, but for this app, I just need a simple solution)

Answer (score 1):

I would manage the state in the root component and make `focused` a property (`this.props.focused`) in all the components you need it. Where you now do the `setState` you call an callback, like so:

```
this.props.onFocusChanged(index)
```

You give this callback as a property to the Landing, and in the `Landing` you give it as a property to the `SocialMenu`. Your App would look something like this:

```
App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { focused: 0 };
    },

    clicked: (index) => {
        this.setState({focused: index});
    },

    render() {
      return (

          <div>
            <Landing onFocusChanged={this.clicked} focused={this.state.focused} />
            <Description />
            <Skills focused={this.state.focused}/>
          </div>

      );
    }
});
```

Comment: how do I bridge the gap between SocialMenu and Landing (Social Menu is the child of Landing, and is where the click event is taking place)?

Comment: Like so: `<SocialMenu onFocusChanged={this.props.onFocusChanged} />` or pass all props through (es6 way): `<SocialMenu {...this.props} />`